# won't let me delete rows in sql server 2005 management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I just want to delete those null rows, i tried to use them and it wont even let me edit them, i get the same error trying to delete or edit them.

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the query you used trying to delete the records?

Comment: sounds you have a design problem on the table, press esc, try to run Delete command from a New Query tab and filter by the null values you want to delete. Can you post the table design or query previously performed?

Comment: You have a table with no primary key.  This is not a good design. Create a primary key field!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem being that there are a number of rows with just nulls, so when you try and delete just one row it will complain as that row is not unique,

Maybe try a SQL statement to delete the rows, such as

```
DELETE FROM sop
WHERE Order IS NULL
```

I have not been able to test this query but it should work for you.

Comment: DELETE FROM [dbo].[sop]
WHERE [Order] IS NULL

Comment: to early in the morning i didn't even think of running a delete query... a homer simpson moment